# How to trace whether member of an attribute is selected or not in cube browser by using mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx

Suppose I have an attribute "District" under "Country" dimension. When dragging this attribute in the cube browser I want to trace which member(s) is/are selected and unselected. I want this to reflect the country total.

For example, Country Z has A,B and C districts.

1. if all A,B and C are selected then country total = A+C
2. if A and C are selected then Country Total = A+C
3. if B and C are selected then country total = B+C
4. if A and B are selected then Country total = A

this 'total' logic may vary on country. Taking another example.

Country Y has three districts - D, E and F

1. if D and E then total = D+E
2. if E and F then total = E+F
3. if D+E+F then total = D+E
4. if D+F then total = D

That's why I want to trace which member under District attribute is being selected or unselected under a specific country by mdx (scope may be) while browsing.

It would be really kind enough if you would help me. Thanks in advance.

Note: There might be other ways to handle the country total. If you have any, please share.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the aggregation logic is already working as described, and the request that you have is to determine within the query which districts are selected e. g. through `WHERE`, subselect, or axes? Is this correct? If so, could you post a sample query where you need this? If this is not correct, please edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: @FrankPl ,
please find the example from this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhVX2slRJ7X3dFFzbV9RWWlzWGFaT2pZTDhDVVVBcnc&usp=drive_web#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this can be implemented easily: When AS calculates the value of a cell, it gets the context of that cell, i. e. the current members of each hierarchy selected in columns, rows, and where axis. But within the cell, the calculation does not know if the selection happened in the where, columns, or row axis, it just knows there is a selection. This way, when the aim is to determine the value for a cell that has Country Y in the rows, you know that country Y is the current value of the geographical hierarchy. But you have no idea if and which districts are in other rows.

There are certainly solutions for single queries, where you know exactly what is where in the query, and there may be solutions for queries where you know at least the structure of the query (like "geography is the second hierarchy on rows, and there is no subselect for geography in the query"), and there may even be clever general solutions, but I would doubt that the latter would be less than about a hundred lines of code.